# How to return an object using Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to build a Rest client with Retrofit 2. This is the first time using this library.

Most of the examples that I have seen normally use a callback function in Android activity or view.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

https://github.com/MeetMe/TwitchTvClient/tree/master/src/com/wdonahue/twitchtvclient

I was wondering if, in the code below, one could return an object of type Appver instead of void?

Thank you!

```
public void GetAppver()
{
    Call<Appver> call = endPoint.GetAppver();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Appver>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Appver> call, Response<Appver> response)
        {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                Appver appver = response.body();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Appver> call, Throwable t) { }
    });
}
```

Comment: you can call some method to simply do something though not feasible to change it

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to have `Appver` because you need to use this object to possibly poulate the UI for instance inside a **RecyclerView**, in this case I guess you cannot avoid to not use void, because you are extending the library. But for sure you can use [Dagger2](https://github.com/google/dagger) or a Singleton although there are some [contraindications](https://medium.com/@programmerr47/singletons-in-android-63ddf972a7e7) to maintain an instance of Appver so that you can use it in an Adapter for instance

Also in real life is rarely used Retrofit2 in this way, usually you implement it with RXJava2 or with Google Architecture components as ViewModel,LiveData and LifeCycle

Comment: Yes, this is actually the main idea. However, I wanted to create all calling methods to the REST server and test them in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Retrofit service methods synchronously.

```
public AppVer GetAppVer() {
    Call<AppVer> call = endPoint.GetAppver();
    Response<AppVer> response;

    try {
        response = call.execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle network communication errors here
    }

    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        // Handle REST service errors here
    }

    return response.body();
}
```

However, as you know, you can't do network communication on the main thread in Android. You have to wrap the call in e.g. a Thread, AsyncTask or Service.

Have a look at the following links how to structure your app.

- Android Architecture Blueprints: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture
- Android Architecture Components: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture